# Create a GUID in a template

Tags: templating

Is there a straightforward way of creating a GUID or some other type of unique identifier within a Twig Template?

I'm aware of [StringHelper.UUID](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/StringHelper#UUID-detail) (mentioned in a different question), but it doesn't look like I can use it directly in a template.

I'm comfortable creating a small plugin to expose this, or alternatively creating a twig filter to use a relevant PHP method, I just didn't want to go re-inventing the wheel if there's already a good solution I don't know about.

Comment: Do you need an actual GUID, or will something unique on the page suffice?

Comment: It did need to be something unique, but not necessarily a GUID. I went with  a solution similar to what Marion suggested with a combination of `date` and `random` twig filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a simple timestamp is unique enough, you can use:

```
{{ now|date('YmdHis') }}
```

Which will give you something like:

```
20150723170500
```

Comment: Similarly, `date('U')` will output a Unix timestamp. And if I remember correctly, lowercase `u` outputs microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly need a GUID, then a small plugin that adds it's own [Twig extension](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addTwigExtension) can add a `{{ getUUID() }}` method that would look like this:

```
public function getUUID()
{
    return StringHelper::UUID();
}
```

Or for other random strings, `{{ getRandomString(12, true) }}`:

```
public function getRandomString($length = 36, $extendedChars = false)
{
    return StringHelper::randomString($length, $extendedChars);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. In the end I went with a solution similar to what Marion suggested with a combination of `date` and `random` twig filters just for simplicity.